# How to apply map function in Spark DataFrame using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use map function on DataFrame in Spark using Java. I am following the documentation which says

> map(scala.Function1 f, scala.reflect.ClassTag evidence$4)
>   Returns a new `RDD` by applying a function to all rows of this DataFrame.

While using the Function1 in map , I need to implement all the functions. I have seen some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790417/java-spark-sql-dataframe-map-function-is-not-working) related to this , but the solution provided converts the `DataFrame` into `RDD`.
How can I use the map function in `DataFrame` without converting it into a `RDD` also what is the second parameter of map ie `scala.reflect.ClassTag<R> evidence$4`

I am using **Java 7** and **Spark 1.6**.

Comment: The map function will return you an RDD, as the documentation says.... In any case, what's preventing you from getting Spark 2 or at least Java 8?

Comment: Yes . The map function anyways returns RDD, But why the provides a map function in DataFrame if can't use it directly ? Actually I am in a learning phashe and we don't know whether the client uses spark 1.7 or spark 2 . So we have to work out in both .

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is about Java 7 and Spark 1.6, but in Spark 2 (and obviously Java 8), you can have a map function as part of a class, so you do not need to manipulate Java lambdas.

The call would look like:

```
Dataset<String> dfMap = df.map(
    new CountyFipsExtractorUsingMap(),
    Encoders.STRING());
dfMap.show(5);
```

The class would look like:

```
  /**
   * Returns a substring of the values in the id2 column.
   * 
   * @author jgp
   */
  private final class CountyFipsExtractorUsingMap
      implements MapFunction<Row, String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 26547L;

    @Override
    public String call(Row r) throws Exception {
      String s = r.getAs("id2").toString().substring(2);
      return s;
    }
  }
```

You can find more details in [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch12/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/books/spark/ch12/lab900LowLevelTransformationAndAction/LowLevelTransformationAndActionApp.java).

Answer (score 0):

I think `map` is not the right way to use on a `DataFrame`. Maybe you should have a look at the examples [in the API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html)

There they show how to operate on `DataFrame`s

Comment: I have used `groupBy`,`agg`,`orderBy` operations in DataFrame. So which are the operation we need to avoid on DataFrame, I did't see any documentation regarding that . anyway thanks for your replay .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dataset directly, need not convert the read data to RDD, its unnecessary consumption of resource.

dataset.map(mapfuncton{...}, encoder); this should suffice your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't give any specific problems, there're some common alternatives to `map` in `DataFrame` like `select`, `selectExpr`, `withColumn`. If the spark sql builtin functions can't fit your task, you can use UTF.